# Laravel morph relation

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord, eloquent

I have 3 types of tables:

- order (id, created_at)
- order_items (id, item_type) in item_type store 1 of 3 values: mandatory, main, secondary.

And others 3:

- order_mandatory_items (id, name, etc..)
- order_main_items (id, name, etc..)
- order_secondary_items (id, name, etc..)

And result models:

- Order
- OrderItem
- OrderMandatoryItem
- OrderMainItem
- OrderSecondaryItem

How i can get all order item of all types using morph relations. To using like this Order::items();

Comment: What is the purpose of the order_items table/class

Comment: Join many types of order items with join table. There are also store quantity, price, discount. In Order mandatory item for example - store specific info to mandatory table, in main item - specific to main and others

Comment: I updated a question for more info